# moment.locale in angular module won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, momentjs

I am very new to angular and trying to modify a piece of code. In an angular module, I have this:

```
angular.module('xxx')
.factory('$browse', ['xxx', 
  function(xxx) { 
    browse.formatItem = function(item) {
      if (item.creationDate) {
        item.creationDatePretty = moment(item.creationDate).format('MM/DD/YY');
      }
    }

    //...
  }

  //...
])
```

All I want to do, is to format `creationDate` using a particular `locale`, rather than hard coding the format. I tried to changed line 6 to:

```
var locale = 'xxx'; //a particular locale
moment.locale(locale);
item.creationDatePretty = moment(item.creationDate);
```

but `moment.locale(locale)` seems to take forever to run (or not run at all?) and I am not able to log what's happening to find out the problem. Any ideas why I can't use `moment.locale()`?

P.S. I even tried to do a `alert(moment.locale());` but that doesn't work either.

Edit: grammar

Comment: i am using moment and this is an example of how i change the locale between english and german:

moment(Date.now()).locale('en').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")

Just change 'en' to 'de' for german.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of `moment` support `lang` rather than `locale`. For example:

```
moment.lang('fr')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular-moment:
https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I'm using an older version of `moment` and `locale` is not introduced there. Thanks for the help anyways